# AWS Custom Authorizer times out

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, serverless, lambda-authorizer

I have serverless lambda function (AWS) that creates an express server using serverless-http. The Custom Authorizer i use to authenticate requests times out after running successfully. below is the policy returned as per CloudWatch logs:

> 2019-02-27T12:06:49.000Z  7b138c38-b316-4ae0-97ad-36242833cefa    policy [ { Action: 'execute-api:Invoke',
>   Effect: 'Allow',
>   Resource: 'arn:aws:execute-api:eu-west-1:xxxx:xxxx/dev/GET/data/age' } ]

After this i get this log:

> 2019-02-27T12:06:54.778Z 7b138c38-b316-4ae0-97ad-36242833cefa Task timed out after 6.01 seconds

My function that was supposed to execute after auth is not even called. i am using async/await to get business against the Authorization token in header.

Here is my authorizer code:

```
if (business) {
  console.log(
    "policy",
    generatePolicy(business, "Allow", event.methodArn).policyDocument.Statement
  );

  callback(null, generatePolicy(business, "Allow", event.methodArn));
  return;
} else {
  callback(null, generatePolicy(null, "Deny", event.methodArn));
  return;
}
```

`generatePolicy` Function:

```
const generatePolicy = function(principalId, effect, resource) {
  const authResponse = {};
  authResponse.principalId = "Business";

if (effect && resource) {
  const policyDocument = {};
  policyDocument.Version = "2012-10-17";
  policyDocument.Statement = [];
  const statementOne = {};
  statementOne.Action = "execute-api:Invoke";
  statementOne.Effect = effect;
  statementOne.Resource = resource;
  policyDocument.Statement[0] = statementOne;
  authResponse.policyDocument = policyDocument;
  authResponse.context = {
  business: principalId
  };
}

 return authResponse;
};
```

`serverless.yml`:

```
myData:
  handler: functions/myData.handler
  events:
    - http:
        path: /data/{proxy+}
        method: ANY
        cors: true
        authorizer: companyAuth
companyAuth:
  handler: middleware/auth.company
  cors: true
```

Note: the same thing works if i run it locally using the `serverless-offline` plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the problem , there can be a high probability that you are using serverless to deploy, and any of your functions are using VPC execution role and that rule must have been also applied to your **Authorizer** function. Now if you've not setup **outbound** rule / public subnet for vpc to fetch the http call, you need to explicitly do either of these

1. Visit the lambda function. Under VPC remove all subnet entries or choose *NONE*
2. Setup Outbound proxy for your vpc using NAT / public subnets .If you want that function to launch under the vpc. The tutorial link is below. I'll quote some important lines.

> The instances in the public subnet can send outbound traffic directly
> to the Internet, whereas the instances in the private subnet can't.
> Instead, the instances in the private subnet can access the Internet
> by using a network address translation (NAT) gateway that resides in
> the public subnet. The database servers can connect to the Internet
> for software updates using the NAT gateway, but the Internet cannot
> establish connections to the database servers.

Follow this https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/VPC_Scenario2.html